# jQuery and Django change_form.html

Tags: jquery, django-admin

I am totally new to jQuery. I spent quite a bit of time researching how to get jQuery to work in the Django Admin, specifically using the change_form.html.

In the {% block extrahead %} in the change_form.html template I eventually found out that I should write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(function(){
        $("#id_fs1").attr("style", "width:10px");
    });

})(django.jQuery);
<script>
```

It worked like a charm but in the end it looks quite convoluted compared to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("id_fs1").style.width = "50px";
</script>
```

(the above was placed in the {% block after_field_sets %})

My question is...
Is there a more elegant way of using jQuery within the Django admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should works as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
        $("#id_fs1").width("10px");
})(django.jQuery);
<script>
```

First steps with jQuery are not easy, but you will find strength of jQuery over time .)

Also using jQuery in django admin is a step more difficult because of namespacing jQuery to not collide with potential another instance of jQuery (that `(django.jQuery)` on end of script, usually it's not required)

Comment: Thanks, that worked too. Am I right that the script does not wait for the DOM to be ready? It seems to only work in the after_field_sets block.

Comment: AFAIK it waits for `domready` event, this is only shorter way how to write it. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/  - there are more ways how to bind script with `ondomready` event in jQuery

Comment: Thank you I will go and check it out.